# Generate ASDoc for ANE library

Tags: air, air-native-extension, asdoc

I'm trying to create ASDoc for Adobe AIR library that use ANE (AIR Native Extension).
When I run the command I get this error:

`Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ExtensionContex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in [another post](http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/05/04/documenting-actionscript-classes-which-make-use-of-air-framework/).
I've add `-external-library-path "../frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc"` to the command.
I execute asdoc in my Flex SDK bin directory.
I use Flex 4.6.0 SDK and AIR 4.0.0.